# ¿por que un metodo final en una clase final?

Tags: java

Me he dado cuenta que puedo tener un método `final` en una clase `final`, y según lo que yo entiendo de `final` con la sola clase `final` ya no se puede implementar ningún método de la clase, así que quisiera saber si hay algo que ignoro o es un error del compilador

Comment: Una clase marcada como `final` indica que ninguna otra puede extender (heredar) de ella (ej. la clase `String` del API estándar de java). Esto no es lo mismo que impedir que se sobrescriban sus métodos. Un método marcado como `final` indica que dicho método no podrá ser sobrescrito por ninguna clase que extienda (herede) de la clase donde este ha sido declarado. Java brinda ambos opciones porque puede ser que sea necesario evitar que un (o varios) método en particular sea sobrescrito en las clases que extiendan de la clase donde este se encuentra, y no imposibilitar que de plano dicha clase pu

Comment: Pero dime si es cierto o no que indicar un método `final` en una clase marcada como `final` no tiene relevancia, por que como dices: "Un método marcado como final indica que dicho método no podrá ser sobrescrito por ninguna **clase que extienda (herede)** de la clase donde este ha sido declarado." y si la clase no deja ser heredada pues ya el `final` del método ¿para que sirve?

Comment: Por supuesto, es redundante, pero no un error. Es algo similar a marcar un método público (no default) de una interfaz como abstracto, que no hace falta, pero tampoco provoca un error.